# Jupyter From Cmd Line in Windows

Tags: cmd, ipython, jupyter

I cannot get jupyter running from my Command line using:

`jupyter notebook`

> jupyter is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file'

But I can get it running from pycharm (slick but with issues). When I take the kernel's IP and Port from pycharm and paste it into my browser I can get it running from there.

I cannot use anaconda because of Arcpy, and I have dug around the jupyter files for some hints.

I'm assuming I need to add something to my path?

Comment: How are you managing your python environments? If you go to the project settings dialog in pycharm, what does it have listed as the interpreter, and is that the same python installation you're using to try to run jupyter from the cmd line?

Comment: Also how did you install jupyter?  Did you `pip install notebook`?

Comment: See this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43239824/748493 which (for me) allowed to launch notebook without adding it to the PATH env. variable on Windows 7

Answer (score 19):

Open cmd and type:

```
where jupyter
```

The output should be a link to Jupyter.
If `where jupyter` doesn't give a link that means the PATH doesn't contain its location.

Add the link of Jupyter to PATH & it would work.

Also if you have `ipython` & have upgraded, try `ipython notebook` on cmd.

Refer: [Running the Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html)

Answer (score 8):

Try to open it using the **Anaconda Prompt**. Just type *jupyter notebook* and press Enter.

`Anaconda Prompt` has existed for a long time and is the correct way of using Anaconda. May be you have a broken installation somehow.

***Try this, if the above doesn't work-***

> In the **Command Prompt** type,
>
> `pip3 install jupyter` if you're using Python3
>
> Else, if you are using Python2.7 then type `pip install jupyter`.

...Some installation should happen...

> Now retry typing `jupyter notebook` in the CMD, it should work now.

Comment: If they're using Conda, why install jupyter through pip...?

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but try using 
`python -m notebook`
This was the only way I was able to get jupyter to start after installing it on the windows 10 command line using pip. I didn't try touching the path.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: the first hurdle of starting with Python is to install it. I downloaded the Anaconda 4.4 for Windows, Python 3.6 64-bit installer.

After sorting the first hurdle of updating the "path" Environmental Variable, and running (at the Python prompt) "import pip", all the instructions I found to install the IPython Notebook generated errors. Submitting the commands "ipython notebook" or "jupyther notebook" from the Windows Command Prompt or the Python prompt generated error messages.

Then I found that the Anaconda installation consists of a host of applications, on of them being the "Jupyter Notebook" application accessible from the Start menu. This application launch (first a shell, then) a browser page.

The application points to a shortcut in , a directory set during the Anaconda installation. The shortcut itself refers to a few locations.

Ready for next hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python 3, try running the command from your virtual environment and or Anaconda command instead of your computer's OS CMD.

Answer (score 0):

To add Jupyter as the windows CLI Command.

You need to add the "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts" into your environment path. This was to solve for me.

Answer (score -1):

Go to **Anaconda Command Prompt** and type **jupyter notebook** and wait for 30 seconds. You can see that your *local host site* will automatically open.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Scripts in your python directory (*C:\Python27\Scripts*) and check whether there is **jupyter** application. If so, you have a successfully installed version of jupyter.

Try adding the path to python scripts. It should work.
eg:  **C:\Python27\Scripts** to 
[Path environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKbmp.png)