# How to fix "'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" when running Jupyter on Windows?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed Jupyter on Windows 10, Python 3.x via

```
$ pip install jupyter
```

The installation works fine, even though I did restart the terminal.

But trying to run

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

gives the following error

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How and where do I find the executable for Jupyter?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that your Python library path is in your system variables (and you can find that path when you pip install Jupyter, you just have to read a bit) and you still experience "command not found or recognized" errors in Windows, you can try:

```
python -m notebook
```

For my Windows at least (Windows 10 Pro), having the `python -m` is the only way I can run my Python packages from command line without running into some sort of error

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ' "
```

or

```
Errno 'THIS_PROGRAM' not found
```

Comment: I use Ipython for many years, and this is the first time I encounter this issue. I figured (as mentioned by others) that it has to do with Windows10 and running `python -m notebook` worked! Thanks for the solution.

Comment: this worked for me but I don't understand why `jupyter notebook` command doesn't work anymore (It stopped working after I reinstalled python on windows 10)

Comment: For JupyterLab use `python -m jupyterlab`

Comment: `python -m notebook` works like a MAGIC, thanks for sharing

Comment: While your answer provides a solution, it doesn't explain why this happens. I answered that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/running-jupyter-via-command-line-on-windows/66938692#66938692

Answer (score 76):

Please try either of these commands first;

```
$ py -m notebook
$ python -m notebook
```

for jupyterlab users

```
py -m jupyterlab
```

Otherwise

```
$ python -m pip install jupyter --user
$ jupyter notebook
```

If this does not work.

pip does not add jupyter directly to path for local.

The output from

```
$ which python
/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/python
```

After some digging I found a executable for jupyter in the folder:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\Scripts\jupyter.exe
```

[Difference between local and roaming folder](https://superuser.com/questions/150012/what-is-the-difference-between-local-and-roaming-folders)

So if you want to be able to execute a program via command line, you need to add it into the %PATH variable. Here is a powershell script to do it. BE SURE TO ADD THE ";" before adding the new path.

```
$ [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\Scripts", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

Update:

if you are using `python3`, switch out `python` with `python3`
but I encourage you to use `pyenv` instead :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've looked for this solutions months back, but gave up. Finally, I find it burred deep in here

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I located and added the path to the `Scripts` folder to the path in my environmental variables and that did the trick.

Comment: I believe this occurs when you install locally with `pip --user`

Comment: If you are using python3, write python3 -m notebook

Comment: `which` is not a Command Prompt or Powershell command, so you would have to run that in Git Bash or something. In Command Prompt, you can instead use `where`.

Comment: python -m notebook worked for me 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 63):

I had the exact same problem and it was driving me crazy. Other answers provide a solution, but they don't explain why you and I are having this problem.

I will try to explain why this is happening and then provide some solutions.

You can go to the end to see the TL;DR.

## 1)What's going on? Why is this error happening?

I'll try to make a step-by-step answer so everything is explained clearly.
If you think it's too basic at the beginning, go to the end of this "article".

I'll first start with common things like running the `python` shell from the terminal or running `pip`. You'll see why you can do that from the terminal and we'll end up on *why* and *how* you can run the `jupyter` notebook from the terminal as well.

Ready? Let's start!

---

**Have you ever wondered why you can type `python` in the terminal (command prompt) and suddenly start the Python interpreter?**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME>python
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

You probably already know (but maybe don't) that this is because Python was added to the Windows `PATH` environment variable. You probably did it at [installation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable) time or [afterwards](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/).

**But, what is this [PATH](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/) environment variable?**

> It basically allows you to run any executables, that are located inside
> the paths specified in the variable, at the command prompt without
> having to give the full path to the executable.

You can check the content of that `PATH` variable with:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path:
        print(path)

C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip
C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs
C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages
... (some other paths were taken out for clarity)
```

You can see this folder: `C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`. This is the place where Python version 3.9 is installed. Let's check its content:

```
<DIR>   DLLs
<DIR>   Doc
<DIR>   etc
<DIR>   include
<DIR>   Lib
<DIR>   libs
<DIR>   Scripts
<DIR>   share
<DIR>   tcl
<DIR>   Tools
        LICENSE.txt
        NEWS.txt
        python.exe
        python3.dll
        python39.dll
        pythonw.exe
        vcruntime140.dll
        vcruntime140_1.dll
```

*Voilà!* We have the `python.exe` file (an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable)). We have a Python executable file in the `PATH`, that's why you can start the Python interpreter from the terminal with just typing `python`. If this wasn't the case you would have to type the full path to the executable file in the terminal:

```
C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME> C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python)
```

Instead of just:

```
C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME> python
```

---

**And what about when you use `pip`?**

It's the same principle. You can run `pip` from the terminal because there is a `pip` executable file in the `PATH` variable.

If you go to `C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\` (which is in the `PATH` showed above) you'll see many executables files. One of them is `pip`. Actually I have three versions: `pip`, `pip3.9` and `pip3`.

The `Scripts` [folder](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable) allows exectuable files to be run from the terminal. Like `pip` or other libraries that you intend to run directly from the terminal. The `Scripts` folder:

> ...is not intended for you, it's for scripts that are installed as
> components of modules that you install. For example, pip is a module,
> but it also has a wrapper script by the same name, pip, which will be
> installed in that directory.
>
> If you put something there and it is properly in your PATH, then it
> should be executable

That wrapper script would be the `pip` executable file. When [this executable](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/6zxadq/what_is_the_cpython27scripts_folder_for/) file is run, it locates the `pip` folder in the Python installation folder and runs `pip`.

But you could also run `pip` directly from the installation folder (`C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages`), without needing the executable `pip` file.

*But, how can you do it?*

I'm glad you ask. There is a Python [way](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) to run modules as the main module (without the need to import it).

```
python -m pip
```

When you run a module directly its name becomes `__main__`. What `-m` does is:

> Search `sys.path` for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__).

What is `__main__`?

> `'__main__'` is the name of the scope in which top-level code executes.
>
> A module’s `__name__` is set equal to `'__main__'` when read from standard
> input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.
> ...

I guess that the `pip` executable does something similar, or at least, has the same effect: to start `pip`.

---

## 2)What does this have to do with the Jupyter Notebook?!

Think of the `Jupyter Notebook` as the same as `pip`. If you want to run `jupyter` in the terminal, you need an executable that it's on the `PATH`.

We have already seen that the executables of modules like `pip` or `jupyter` are located here `C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\`.

If I check the content of the folder I see this:

```
easy_install-3.9.exe
easy_install.exe
f2py.exe
jsonschema.exe
jupyter-bundlerextension.exe
jupyter-console.exe
jupyter-nbconvert.exe
jupyter-nbextension.exe
jupyter-notebook.exe
jupyter-qtconsole.exe
jupyter-serverextension.exe
jupyter-trust.exe
pip.exe
pip3.9.exe
pip3.exe
```

I see the already mentioned `pip`, `pip3.9` and `pip3`. But I don't see `jupyter` (the word "*jupyter*" alone).

If I type `jupyter` in the terminal I get the error that started all:

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Finally we've reached an answer to your question!!!

---

**'jupyter' is not recognized as a command because there is no executable file in the `Scripts` folder called `jupyter`.**

---

So, let's try a different executable. What about `jupyter-notebook`?

*BINGO!* The notebook is running!

```
Serving notebooks from local directory:
C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at:
http://localhost:8888/?token=... (edited)
or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=... (edited)
Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

I don't know why I don't have a `jupyter` executable called 'jupyter'. The [official documentation](https://jupyter.org/install) says to use `jupyter notebook` on the terminal, but it seems that in some cases it doesn't work. And I think it has to do with what I mentioned above: *there is no `jupyter` exectuable in the `Scripts` folder.*

---

If you remember, I told you that you can run `pip` as the main module using `python -m pip`.

It happens that you can do the same with `jupyter`.We just need to know how to call it. As in with `pip`, we have to check the folder where 3rd party libraries are installed: `C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages`.

You'll see `jupyter_console`, but this just creates an interactive notebook in the terminal, not exactly what you were looking for. You're also going to find folders ending with `.dist.info`, like `jupyter_console-6.4.0.dist-info`. This is just [metadata](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-contents) of the Wheel Binary Package builder. You'll also see a folder like `jupyterlab_pygments`, but [that's](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/master?urlpath=lab/tree/demo) for `JupyterLab`. We want to use the classic Jupyter notebook.

What we want is to run `notebook`. How do we know this?

You'll see in the folder `site-packages` the folder (*package*) `notebook`. Inside there is a [file called](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/__main__.py) `__main__.py`:

```
#__main__.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from notebook import notebookapp as app
    app.launch_new_instance()
```

It's calling `notebookapp.py` [which is](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/notebookapp.py) a *"A tornado based Jupyter notebook server."* Yes, this is what we need.

We can [see](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/notebookapp.py) that `launch_new_instance` in the `notebookapp` calls `launch_instance()`, [which](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/blob/e69a436529838dce8b41e6d4508f94930c87b559/jupyter_core/application.py#L251) "*launches an instance of a Jupyter Application*".

Perfect! We are in the correct folder. To run the jupyter notebook from the Python interactive shell we have to run the notebook package with:

```
python -m notebook
```

---

## 3)*** SUMMARY: SOLUTION ***

tl;dr:

I have explained and showed why this error is happening.

Now let's summarize the solutions:

1. To know the name of the `jupyter` executable (in the `Scripts` folder), so you can run directly from the terminal (Command Prompt) as:

   ```
    jupyter notebook
   ```

or as:

```
    jupyter-notebook
```

Or whatever name you have.

2. Run the notebook as the main module from Python:

   ```
    python -m notebook
   ```

I hope this helps you as much as it helped me. I'm open to your comments and suggestions.

Comment: However, `jupyter notebook` does not work whereas `jupyter-notebook` works flawlessly. Refer to [this post](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/error-while-running-jupyter-lab-or-jupyter-lab-on-windows-machine/10341/9?u=itsdebartha) where I found this anomaly.

Comment: @its_deb yes, that happens. In my answer I tried to provide an explanation. Thanks for the post.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation, thank you. I'm still unable to find the executables for my pip packages - I've installed python via the Windows app store so the python executable is at `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`

Comment: I've never used to Windows apps store. Have you tried using pip?

Comment: You helped me a lot to understand the idea behind this weird error, thanks a lot!

Comment: Smart chap, right from the basics, kudos @GuzmanOjero

Comment: `python -m notebook` works for me!!! thanks

Answer (score 44):

I had the same problem, but

```
py -m notebook
```

worked for me.

Comment: No module named notebook

Answer (score 15):

I got Jupyter notebook running in Windows 10. I found the easiest way to accomplish this task without relying upon a distro like Anaconda was to use Cygwin.

In Cygwin install python2, python2-devel, python2-numpy, python2-pip, tcl, tcl-devel, (I have included a image below of all packages I installed) and any other python packages you want that are available. This is by far the easiest option.

Then run this command to just install jupyter notebook:

```
python -m pip install jupyter
```

Below is the actual commands I ran to add more libraries just in case others need this list too:

```
python -m pip install scipy

python -m pip install scikit-learn

python -m pip install sklearn

python -m pip install pandas

python -m pip install matplotlib

python -m pip install jupyter
```

If any of the above commands fail do not worry the solution is pretty simple most of the time. What you do is look at the build failure for whatever missing package / library.

Say it is showing a missing pyzmq then close Cygwin, re-open the installer, get to the package list screen, show "full" for all, then search for the name like zmq and install those libraries and re-try the above commands.

Using this approach it was fairly simple to eventually work through all the missing dependencies successfully.

[Cygwin package list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbqVu.png)

Once everything is installed then run in Cygwin goto the folder you want to be the "root" for the notebook ui tree and type:

```
jupyter notebook
```

This will start up the notebook and show some output like below:

```
$ jupyter notebook
[I 19:05:30.459 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: 
[I 19:05:30.459 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 19:05:30.459 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: 
[I 19:05:30.459 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time, to login with a token:

http://localhost:8888/?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add the following to your path

```
C:\[Python Installation path]\Scripts
```

e.g. `C:\Python27\Scripts`

It will start working for jupyter and every other pip install you will do here on.

Answer (score 6):

**In [Python 3.7.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) for Windows 10. After installation, I use these commands.**

```
1. pip install notebook
2. python -m notebook
```

**OR**

> C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts
>   .

**For my pc python-scripts are located in the above path. You can add this path in environment variables. Then run command.**

```
1. jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 4):

Check whether you have given python PATH in environmental variables properly.
If not, then set python path. Then use:

```
$ python -m notebook
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Anaconda distribution, make sure when installing it that you check the "Change PATH" option.

Comment: After installing Anaconda on a Windows machine:  
Add the Python location to the system var "Path." 
Use Windows search to find the system editor to change the PATH environment variable [enter the entire path, including c:\ & make sure to start with ";" seperator] or use the command line "set path=%path%;C:\users\your-path-here\" 

...Now you can invoke Python from any command prompt location.

Answer (score 3):

first you should make sure that you are put your python path in your system variables ..
Then try run this

```
python -m pip install jupyter --user
```

and then
run this

```
py -m notebook or  jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 you can use `ipython notebook`. It works for me.

Comment: `[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand 'ipython notebook' is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.` SSL: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`

Answer (score 2):

I added

```
 c:\users\[user]\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages
```

to the path and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

## windows CMD

#### for default install (just check "add path" and "next" when installing)

```
python -m notebook
```

#### for custom install in C:\

```
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem for me was that I was running the `jupyter` command from the wrong directory.

Once I navigated to the path containing the script, everything worked.

Path-
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts`

Answer (score 1):

100% working solution:

Follow these steps:

1. Open the folder where you downloaded "python-3.8.2-amd64.exe" setup or any other version of python package
2. Double click on "python-3.8.2-amd64.exe'
3. Click "Modify"
4. You will see "Optional features"
5. Click "next"
6. Select "Add python to environment variables"
7. Click "install"
8. Then u can run jupyter in any  desired folder u desire

```
    E.g  open "cmd" command prompt

    Type : 
    E: 

    E:\>jupyter notebook

    It will get started without showing

    'Jupyter' is not recognized
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have two python version installed:
1. Python 3.8.2: This was installed independently
2. Python 3.7.6: This was installed along with Anaconda 3

Multiple versions caused conflict even after setting the path variables correctly.

I have uninstalled the Python 3.8.2 and after restart, the command

```
jupyter notebook
```

Worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a batch file and search for Jupiter in your windows search and ooen its properties and you will get this string.
**D:\anaconda3\python.exe D:\anaconda3\cwp.py D:\anaconda3 D:\anaconda3\python.exe D:\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py "%USERPROFILE%/"**
after getting this you can create a jupitor.bat file with this content it that
and you can save that file in a script folder in d or any drive and add the path of your script file in your environmental path

and then you can easly call this by typing jupitor in cmd.

Answer (score 1):

To install I used
"pip install notebook" in windows command line

To run python -m notebook did not work for me, but python3 -m notebook worked

Answer (score 1):

First run this command

> pip install jupyter

then add system variable path , this path is where jupyter and other scripts are located

PATH = C:\Users<userName>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts

e.g PATH=C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts

After that we can run jupyter from any folder/directory

> jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

I just found that error when I first intalled and run the jupyter notebook. Then I found the executable (.exe) file from
`C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts`.
The actual file name was `"jupyter-notebook"`.
The installation guide says it as `"jupyter notebook"` to run the server. You have to run the command `"jupyter-notebook"` in the command line and it will be run. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it through pip installation,

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\<yourpythonfolder>\Scripts
```

Adding this to your path is missing for 'jupyter notebook' command to run

Answer (score 1):

you can should type in your windows command-line `python -m notebook`

if you can another response than you can re-install the jupyter `pip install jupyter`  ,

After complete the successful installation type again in your command-line `python -m notebook`...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my user's folder had a space in folder name.

After creating a new user and switching to that windows user, windows shortcuts and links from within' Anaconda worked fine.

Windows 8.1 64 Bit. Latest Anaconda.

Note: I ended up uninstalling an reinstalling Anaconda but my sense is the problem was really just the space in the windows user username/user folder.

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.6.3. Here after installing Jupyter through command '*python -m pip install jupyter*', '*jupyter notebook*' command didn't work for me using windows command prompt.

But, finally '*python -m notebook*' did work and made jupyter notebook to run on local.

http://localhost:8888/tree

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved stated issue, hope it helps:

1. install python 3.7 using official website for python, while installing  include installing PATH by checking it's box
2. after that open cmd (be sure to open it after step 1) and write: pip install jupyter ENTER
3. now you should be able to open jupyter notebook by using command: jupyter notebook

Seems simple, but it may as well help.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10:
If you used anaconda3 for Jupyter notebook installation and forgot to check the box to add the environment variables to the system during installation, you need to add the following environment variables to the "Path" variable manually:
 (search windows settings for Edit environment variables")

[Environment variables for Anaconda3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJVbD.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed jupyter with 
"python -m pip install jupyter" command 
instead of
"$ pip install jupyter" command 
then follow these steps:

1. Create a notepad
2. Change its extension from ".txt" to ".ipynb"
3. Right click it and click "open with"
4. In the pop up, go to - C:\Users\<"windows_user_name">\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts
5. Click on "jupyter-lab.exe"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in windows7, as i just recoverd my computer with the help of recovery point and after that notebook just stopped working. I tried to change the path setting but nothing was working so I just simply uninstalled the python with the application from which it was installed and after that I installed it again. After that I installed jupyter notebook again and then it worked fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just installed JupyterLab on top of my Python 3.8/pip enabled Win10 machine, so I ran into these startup problem with windows.
If everything is ok (check that you have PATH for Python, eg. C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts) you simply run:

jupyter-lab.exe

and that's it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add system variable path, this path is where jupyter and other scripts are located

PATH -->

```
`C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts`
```

Like in my laptop PATH is:

```
"C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts"
```

After that, You will be able to run jupyter from any folder & any directory by running the below command

> **jupyter notebook**

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Finally searched where jupyter.exe directory was located on my computer. For some reason it was under
C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume4\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python

Whereas the Python is
C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python

So I copied full Python39 folder from VTRoot to main Python39 python folder in AppData. And the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

First check where your python is installed by heading over to

```
C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
```

this is the path usually you will find python installed. After this type in

```
cd..  to get one step out of the Scripts folder
```

After this install jupyter in here using:

```
$ pip install jupyter
```

The installation was fine and when I tried to open the jupyter notebook, it gave me the following error.

```
'jupiter is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I checked a lot of resources but still, I faced the same problem. After doing a lot of stuff from the internet, I myself figured out that maybe due to some updates(for some users) it won't open by typing the command

```
jupyter notebook
```

Instead, you have to type

```
jupyter-notebook
```

The only thing I was missing was this Hyphen-minus. Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and installed jupyter using pip on windows 10. I was actually trying to install an R kernel for jupyter and it did not work. Eventually the solution from Hao Liang at [jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056164/jupyter-client-has-to-be-installed-but-jupyter-kernelspec-version-exited-wit) worked.

However if you want to be able to run "jupyter notebook" please try the following.

1. Find the location of the jupyter file, by looking at the location returned after typing `pip show jupyter` in ms-dos prompt. For me it was c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python39_64\lib\site-packages
   in that folder there is a file jupyter.py that is the root command that call the different jupyter modules.
2. Add the location of the file to the PATH (using system environment variable)
3. If not done already add the folder of the python exectuable to the PATH too (for me it was c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python39_64).
4. Now add python file extensions to the PATHEXT environment variable (adding ".PY;" to PATHEXT)
5. In a command prompt run as administrator, run the following two commands:

   `assoc .py=Python.File`

   `ftype Python.File=c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python39_64\\python.exe "%1" %*`
6. Open a new command and type "jupyter notebook", it should now work.

Answer (score -1):

I know there are so many answers here, but this might help others.

1. Set the environment variables for your username.
2. check whether the notebook is installed,
   jupyter --version
   This will list all the Jupyter core packages
3. if the notebook says "not installed", execute the below command
   pip install notebook

[image]

Comment: You should past the terminal output as text formatted as code