# jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I have already installed Jupyter notebook in my ubuntu 16.04 machine. In jupyter notebook there is by default python installed. Now I want to use R from jupyter notebook.

To do so I followed [IRkernel installation link](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel) and run below commands:

```
install.packages('devtools')

devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
```

But when I run 
`IRkernel::installspec()` command it shows below error:

> jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127

I am now confused why this error occurs.

Comment: Did you run it from the terminal?

Comment: Yes I run this command from terminal.

Comment: is jupyter on your path?

Comment: I had the same issue. Solved mine by running R in the console as Admin.

Comment: @ShalomJohn Your comment is the only thing that helped me! It should be an answer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Running this command from RStudio will show this error. When you run this command from command line/ terminal then everything will be fine.

So just type `R` from your command line.

Then Run below commands:

```
install.packages('devtools')

devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
```

[image]

```
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Comment: nope, I have the issue when running directly the R console

Comment: You saved my day

Answer (score 35):

1. If Anaconda is installed and the Jupyter-Notebook with it (should be the standard install), open up the Anaconda prompt, not the Windows command prompt or the Anaconda Navigator
2. Look up the executable of R (not Rgui or Rstudio), it should be somewhere like C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin and remember the path typing 
   `cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin` and start R by typing `R`
3. typing `IRkernel::installspec()`
4. Now you can start an R kernel within Jupyter-Notebook

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. Can you explain why it works from anaconda prompt and not from windows prompt

Answer (score 17):

On some Windows systems you may not succeed even if you run R from cmd / powershell. That's the case on my machine. My workaround is to run R from Anaconda Prompt (if you installed Jupyter via Anaconda). You may need to specify the full path if R is not on your `PATH`.

I think this is some problem related to the `PATH`, however I had no luck adding `Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client` to my system `PATH`.

Comment: In my case of Windows10, **C:\Users\[user name]\Anaconda3\Scripts** shoud be added to system **PATH**.

Comment: This also worked for me, although my path was `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts`.

Comment: this worked for me on my win 10 laptop. On win 7 desktop it was not needed.  Might be how anaconda is installed on 7 vs 10?

Answer (score 15):

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 with R installed in /usr/bin/R and Python in /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python.  I ran into a number of path related problems when trying to tell Jupyter where to find the kernel for my R installation.  Regardless of how I ran R the IRkernel::installspec() would not work in R.  I found success by making the connection using jupyter kernelspec from the command line.  Specifically this is what worked for me.

From within R:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("IRkernel/IRkernel")
system.file('kernelspec', package = 'IRkernel')
```

The last line should give you the location of Jupyter will need to find the kernel.  Mine was /home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/IRkernel/kernelspec

From the command line:

1. inspect the path that you receive when you were in R.  There should
   be a .json file in it.
2. `jupyter kernelspec list`  (run this to be
   sure that jupyter is in your path, you should see information about
   the current available kernels.
3. `jupyter kernelspec install /home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/IRkernel/kernelspec --name 'R' --user` (you will use path that you received while working in R which could be different)
4. `jupyter kernelspec list` (this list should now include R)
5. restart jupyter

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. PS: I installed Jupyter using pip3, not Anaconda.

Comment: This worked for my in Parallels virtual box. Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04. I also installed Jupyter using pip.

Comment: Finally got this working using your instructions, thx (Linux Mint 21.2)!

Answer (score 10):

I have solved with this:

**sudo ln -s /home/'my user name'/anaconda3/bin/jupyter /usr/bin/jupyter**

Comment: That doesn't look like a great fix to me. Is that path accessible to other users on the system who want to use jupyter from /usr/bin? Can't you just add your ~/anaconda3/bin path to your PATH in your .profile or .bash_profile? (Doesn't that happen automatically?)

Comment: Hello Rup. This link the two directions. It tells R where to find the Jupyter runner and there having the kernel.  Once Jupyter has the R kernel I think it could be open to every user.

Comment: Try Making a Link before reinstalling software

Answer (score 8):

I tried to install IRkernel on my Windows machine. I experienced a similar problem when I ran from within R:

```
> IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)
Error in IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE) : 
  jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 1.
```

I did not use conda to install Jupyter on my machine, but pip. I have some programmes installed which use python under the hood. It means that I have more than one Python instance on my machine and more Jupyter instances too. To be sure I was referencing the right Jupyter instance, I did this:

```
> setwd('C:/usr/lib/Python36-32/Scripts')
> IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)
[InstallKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec ir in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels\ir
```

Besides Python, I can now also use R within my notebooks.

Comment: This works for me on windows with python environment via venv. 1.  devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel'). 2. setwd("c:/path/to/python/environment/Scripts"). 3. IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)

Answer (score 6):

Here a way to overcome this problem. I have installed IRkernel with anaconda in my mac (I guess is the same on Linux). The below command also works in windows to be run on Anaconda shell and pressing y after a y/n prompt (you can also refer https://medium.com/@kyleake/how-to-install-r-in-jupyter-with-irkernel-in-3-steps-917519326e41)

I typed:

```
conda install -c r r-irkernel
```

Then I started started R typing:

```
R
```

Finally, I have install the kernelspec to tell Jupyter about IRkernel, with the option user=FALSE for installation in the global environment:

```
IRkernel::installspec(user=FALSE)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked for me! Windows 10 running Anaconda + Vscode (Jupyter notebook)

Answer (score 4):

In windows 10 sys
you just move the 3 files in your R library (install 'IRkernel' before this step)
[image]
to
your jupyter-lab "ir" path
[image]

Hope it helps u!

Comment: I don't use anaconda. I just use pip! It's simple!

Comment: This also works well under Linux and for "JupyterHub" - I had to copy it from R's library to /opt/tljh/user/share/jupyter/kernels/ and it worked like a charm

Comment: this works for me: Windows 10, pip installed jupyter. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much! It works for me on windows 10 using pip.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem and resolved it with ease following these steps

PC specs: macOS version 10.14.6

1. Make sure R is installed if not find [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) how to do so.
2. Make sure you have Jupyter Notebook installed if not find that [here](https://jupyter.org/install) how.
3. Go to the terminal or use Launchpad to launch R, then install following package: `devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')`.
4. Find out where it's installed using: `system.file('kernelspec', package = 'IRkernel')` and use the path (mine was : `/Users/ali/Library/R/4.0/library/IRkernel/kernelspec`) you get here in the commond below.
5. Go to the terminal again and type this : `jupyter kernelspec install  /Users/ali/Library/R/4.0/library/IRkernel/kernelspec --name 'R' --user`.
6. Then the last thing is to check the kernal list  and restart notebook using cmd 4 and 5 from [@Bryan Prazen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65042753/23300343) above.

Comment: I installed r in brew, then did `install.packages('IRkernel')` in rstudio, and I had to do this command on step 5: `jupyter kernelspec install /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.2/lib/R/library/IRkernel/kernelspec --name 'R' --user`

Answer (score 2):

Adding this for anyone, who googling and getting stuck on this issue may benefit from this simple learning. I got the same error, as above, followed the instructions above (while launching R in Terminal):

```
IRkernel::installspec() 
Error in IRkernel::installspec() : 
    jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
```

In Bash I ran:

```
Mac-Pro:~ $ jupyter kernelspec --version
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

*Duh*, I had no Jupyter installed. Install Jupyter (on mac, using brew) with: `brew install jupyter`. Installation instructions for other OS's can be found [here](http://jupyter.org/install).

All now working fine.

Comment: Similar issue here on Windows (I think it might be because I chose Miniconda). But I did have to run "conda install jupyter_client" to get installspec() to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but the fix was different:

Make sure you also have anaconda install on your system! (or at least jupyter)
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but in my case, I have jupyter installed in a virtual environment, so I had to start R after installing the virtual environment in order for IRkernel::installspec() to succeed.

Comment: wow this was the answer I required. I forgot that I installed jupyter in virtual env and I was trying hard with all the other solutions and after looking your answer only then I realized my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while trying to install my environment as kernel in Jupyter. First I had created a new environment, installed R, IRkernel and devtools from within conda prompt, then runned R typing `R` from the prompt and typing

```
IRkernel::installspec(name = 'myenvname', displayname = 'myenvname')
```

I had the same error. 
I **solved** simply in this way:

```
conda install -c anaconda jupyter_client
```

And then retyping the previous code it just worked.

Answer (score 1):

For mac users:

I came across the same problem. You should call `IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)` in the terminal through R. I solved it this way, and I bet you could do the same:

1. Call `R.home()` in R console
2. You shall get `[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"`
3. Add `/bin/R` to path nlike this: `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R`
4. In terminal, paste this path `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R`and enter.
5. Now you are using R in terminal. Call`IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)`
   And it shall be solved then.

Answer (score 1):

I was installing Jupyter Notebook for R in Linux and when I was adding `IRkernel` for Jupyter, I got this same error. Then I installed `jupyter-client` by using Linux terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install jupyter-client
```

After this, no other error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; I added the following in the ~/.bashrc (and `source`) and then tried running `IRkernel::installspec()` and it worked:

```
export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but none of the above solutions worked for me. I was using Debian 9 with the default versions of Python and R. I had to delete installed programs and compile latest versions of both from source. For Python compiling, I had to use [this configuration](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/173).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users, after installing Anaconda, you should restart your system so Anaconda prompt appears on start. After opening Anaconda  prompt, enter

```
IRkernel::installspec()
```

This time it will work since I think restarting causes `PATH` of the system to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use conda - I have python virtual env and R installed.
I don't know if it matters but I'm running on ubuntu for windows (WSL) (might be the cause of my error, might be unrelated).
In the console, it recognized jupyter. Inside R console I installed IRkernel but IRkernel::installspec() gave me the error above (didn't recognize jupyter).
I couldn't find a solution that worked, so I am writing here what solved it for me.
I found the internals of installspec [here](https://rdrr.io/github/IRkernel/IRkernel/src/R/installspec.r).
Check before hand where is your jupyter installed with `which jupyter`
and run R from command line.
Then, run the following code (adjusted from the link above):

```
 srcdir <- system.file('kernelspec', package = 'IRkernel')
 tmp_name <- tempfile()
 dir.create(tmp_name)
 file.copy(srcdir, tmp_name, recursive = TRUE)
 spec_path <- file.path(tmp_name, 'kernelspec', 'kernel.json')
 library(jsonlite)
 spec$argv[[1]] <- file.path(R.home('bin'), 'R')
 spec$display_name <- 'R'
 write(toJSON(spec, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE), file = spec_path)
 args <- c('kernelspec', 'install', '--replace', '--name', 'ir', file.path(tmp_name, 'kernelspec'))
 system2('/path/to/jupyter', args)  <--- here you copy paste the path you got earlier with pwd
 unlink(tmp_name, recursive = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have installed: R language, Python&Anaconda which automatically comes with jupyter.
2. Check if your jupyter is working by opening it from the (just regular windows) command prompt: `jupyter-lab`. This should open jupyter environment in browser and if you are still unsuccessful, shows only python.
3. Run the code directly in the R console, not in an R interface like R studio. Find this by searching for R [version number] on your PC: example R 4.2.1.
4. **RUN R CONSOLE AS ADMINISTRATOR (credit: ShalomJohn)**
5. Run the code previously suggested in different answers:

   ```
    install.packages('devtools')
    devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
    IRkernel::installspec()
   ```
6. If you look at the Jupyter-lab window, R should  now show up next to Python

Answer (score 0):

I gradually realise that the error message is the key answer. According to a similar error with code 1, I solved it only by installing the Jupyter client ... ...

Comment: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/jupyter_client

Answer (score 0):

**Check your conda virtual environments.**
For me, the `IRkernel::installspec()` was giving the same error until I remembered that my *jupyter* package was only installed in one of my conda environments. So I just activated it with

```
conda activate My_environment_name
```

in Anaconda prompt (I opened it as administrator), and then the standard instructions worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the sequence was exactly precise in the order I'm going to type but it did work. So in case it helps someone:

If `IRkernel::installspec()` result in an error message like:

`jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 1`

it may require prior installation of `devtools`. As explained [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55626636/4089351):

From Ubuntu cmd line (not from within R):

`sudo apt install r-cran-devtools`

And then update Jupyter and install Jupyterlab:

`pip install --upgrade jupyter`

`pip3 install jupyterlab`

Now try again from within R:

`IRkernel::installspec()`

Answer (score -1):

Assume that you have already run `R` in the terminal. You can first call `library('IRkernel')`, press Enter, then call `installspec()` or `installspec(user=FALSE)`.

For me, simply calling `IRkernel::installspec()` will always raise the error you mentioned in your question. I don't know why what I did solved this problem on my centos server.