# jupyter notebook not running through command line

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run jupyter notebook through command line using below command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

I am using Windows 10 & using jupyter notebook through Anaconda package.

I am getting below error:

>
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard : not seems duplicate as in that question, user installed using pip and in my case, I am using Anaconda package. I am not sure where jupyter notebook lies in Anaconda package so not able to set path.

Comment: The [answer by AZBlue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44866672/1288) covers that. You're going to need to know where you installed it.

Comment: I was looking for exact path where does jupyter notebook exists. I got it. It's in ..\Anaconda3\Scripts.
Filename : jupyter-notebook-script.py