# Error installing Jupyter on Windows 10 device using pip3- Jupyter 1.0.0 being installed, and not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, jupyter

I am trying to install Jupyter on my Windows 10 machine using command prompt. I have already installed Python(version 3.7.1). I am referring to [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dne4WKK8WN4&feature=youtu.be) for installing Jupyter.

On executing the command, `pip3 install jupyter`, it proceeds with the installation, but the last line displayed is:

```
Successfully installed jupyter-1.0.0.
```

After this, when I try to run `jupyter notebook` command to start Jupyter, I get the following error:

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have followed all the steps of the above mentioned video and run the commands after appropriately changing the path, and yet this is happening.

To solve this issue, I upgraded pip and setuptools, and tried installing Jupyter again, but I get the same error. My current pip version is 19.0.1 and setuptools version is 40.8.0.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Why is Jupyter 1.0.0 being installed? How do I install the latest version of Jupyter? And how do I get it to run? (I know I might as well install Anaconda but I would prefer to install Jupyter this way).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running jupyter via command line on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/running-jupyter-via-command-line-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Conda provides managing multiple environments and jupyter can be started easily on any environment from anaconda navigator.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ro9l0eapoJU

Go throught the above video and let know if any issues in setup.. Will help out

Comment: Hey! I'm confused. The video you shared is about how to integrate Jupyter Notebooks with Anaconda, isn't it?  I do not have Anaconda, nor do I have Jupyter(yet). I am trying to install Jupyter without having to install Anaconda. Can you help me out with that? I am getting errors as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Windows 10 machine and I have Jupyter installed on it along with a basic installation of python.
What I would like to know is when you wrote the command `pip3 install jupyter` do you have a version of python2 installed as well on your machine?

Just to get started, you can open the **Command Prompt or PowerShell in Windows 10 as an Administrator**, and install Jupyter with the following command `pip install jupyter`. This should install jupyter notebook on your machine. You can then start the notebook with your usual command `jupyter notebook`.

P.S: I have Python 3 installed on my machine Python 3.6.6

Comment: Hey! I do not have a version of Python 2 installed. I tried what you suggested and ran 'pip install jupyter' as an administrator, but it is still installing Jupyter 1.0.0, and the command 'jupyter notebook' is giving me the same error as before.

Comment: When installing Python via the MSI installer file, did you install it for all users? or did you simply go the usual way of punching "Next" til it installed everything?

Comment: I don't really remember what I did, but most likely I went the usual way of punching next till everything was installed

Answer (score -1):

This issue arises with `python 3.7` and later versions.
I currently have Python 3.9.2 and a 64-bit machine.

Follow these Steps in the cmd Window:

1. Install `pywinpty` by using [Gholke s Collection](link address here)
2. Download [`Pywinpty`](link address here)
3. Copy the full path to the file you downloaded. In my case it was: `https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywinpty`.
4. After successfully installing Pywinpty, run: `pip install jupyter`
5. Now launch the notebook by calling: `jupyter notebook`

[image]

Comment: All code, instructions, for messages, et al necessary to solve the OP's issue must be *embedded as text* within the post. Links are fine as long as essential elements from the link is *also* embedded in the post, for if the link were to become unavailable, or the content to change, your answer would become useless, & SO quality suffers. Code, error messages, data, etc must be selectable text, not images. Please edit to use standardised SO markdown formatting. Also remove cruft/hype from the text. Exact code/instructions are required - otherwise it should be left as a Comment instead.