# What does the term: Python -m mean?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, command-prompt

I'm trying to run jupyter notebook.

For some reason, I get the error that jupyter is not a command :(

I looked at [Running jupyter via command line on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/running-jupyter-via-command-line-on-windows) user6094431's answer.

What does `Python -m mean`?

As in `python -m notebook`.

I used `pip` to install Jupyter.

"jupyter notebook" doesn't work btw.

Comment: This topic is extensively explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-m` you're asking about is one of the [command line flags that the Python interpreter recognizes](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m). It tells the interpreter to take the next thing on the command line and treat it as a module name, like in an `import` statement. The named module will be used as the main module in the interpreter, like a script.

If you want to follow the advice of that answer, you need to go to an command line, and type in, literally `python -m notebook`. The first word is the program to run, the `-m` and `notebook` are arguments.

On Windows, the Python interpreter might not be in your PATH by default. If that's the case, you can instead try running `py`, which is a helper program that can run any installed Python interpreter. If you have more than one interpreter installed, you might need to pass a flag telling `py` which version you want (e.g. `py -3.7 -m notebook`). Extra arguments to `py` will be passed on to the Python interpreter, so `-m` should work fine.