# Can't open Jupyter notebook from command prompt

Tags: windows, anaconda, jupyter, command-prompt

I have always opened the jupyter notebooks from the Anaconda prompt. The problem is that whenever I try to open the Jupyter notebook from the command  prompt, the following error is displayed:

[Picture of the Error shown on my command prompt window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q99Cz.png)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

What am I doing wrong ? What should I do?

Comment: What is the purpose of try to type and run Jupyter notebook on `cmd` when you can run it by using windows search bar.

Comment: Kalana, I see your point. You are right but can you help me understand why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Is this help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/running-jupyter-via-command-line-on-windows/43239824#43239824

Comment: Thank you..I will try this one out.

Answer (score 2):

Opening Jupyter Notebook from command prompt is useful, especially when you would like to open the Jupyter Notebook from a specific folder.

The following 2 steps might help you to resolve this issue.

1. open command prompt

   activate base

The prompt might change to begin with "(base)", which is expected. Then type,

```
Jupyter-notebook
```

If Jupyter notebook opens up now, this means Jupyter is correctly installed within your conda environment. In OS like Windows 10, it was an expected behavior not to recognize Python outside of Conda environment, which extends to Jupyter Notebook as well.

- If the 1st step works properly, then add the below paths to your
  environment variable. If you would not like to add the path to your
  system environment variable, you can choose to update in your
  account environment variable.
- In windows 10 >> search "environments" and "Edit environment
  variables for your account"
- Select "PATH" and edit.
- Add below paths

> C:\Users\\Anaconda3;
>       C:\Users\\Anaconda3\Scripts;
>       C:\Users\\Anaconda3\Lib; 
>       C:\Users\\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
>       C:\Users\\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;

Now you should be able to open Jupyter Notebook directly from command prompt.