# can't launch python Jupyter Notebook from cmd prompt

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

I have been launching the jupyter notebook app directly by clicking an icon, but I can't launch it from the command prompt on Windows 10. I've tried typing `Jupyter notebook` and `python -m notebook` with no success:

```
jupyter is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

and

```
No module named notebook
```

respectively. From reading similar posts, I see it's something related to the Windows environment paths, but I'm not sure how to add Jupyter. Help, please? (Notice that I can access plain `python` from the command prompt; also, notice that [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693157/cant-open-jupyter-notebook-from-command-prompt), involves a different error).

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked appears to address your issue; the .dll error in that question is also solved by using the correct path.

As posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693157/cant-open-jupyter-notebook-from-command-prompt), add the listed Anaconda folders to your local path, and remember to start Jupyter using

```
jupyter-notebook
```

Comment: You're right, it was an issue w the path + activating the base, both of which I had to do some research before I could fix. I won't make your response as the right answer, because it provides useful references but not the solution I needed, but admittedly this is a problem with my question. Thanks!