# how start and install with jupyterlab notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to start working by jupyter notebook. I am using Mac. I did the following commands in terminal.

`pip install jupyterlab`

`pip install notebook`

They were installed well now in terminal I type :

```
jupyter notebook
```

And get :

```
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try anaconda, the best and easiest way to use jupyter notebook

Comment: To follow on that good advice by @Zhefu Peng, see my first comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60724227/8508004) for some useful links..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install --upgrade notebook
```

Then run

```
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, you may have some python version inconsistency, always install PiPy packages with this command:

```
    python -m pip install jupyter
```

Most of time, this type of installation, resolve many issues.

If your issue not solved, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/running-jupyter-via-command-line-on-windows), this is about your similar problem with Jupyter in Windows.

Comment: I completed the my answer with a link, please read the link. if not solved, mention again.