# Launch Juypter in Mac

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried to follow [this doc](https://jupyter.org/install) to launch jupyter in my Mac, but it did not work. Could anyone help?

```
Ties-MBP:10studio-4 chengtie$ pip --version
pip 19.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Ties-MBP:10studio-4 chengtie$ jupyter --version
4.4.0

Ties-MBP:10studio-4 chengtie$ pip install notebook
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Requirement already satisfied: notebook in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (5.7.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.4.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook) (4.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.1 in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress; python_version == "2.7" in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook) (1.0.22)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook) (17.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.2.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook) (5.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2.1->notebook) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2.1->notebook) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2.1->notebook) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook) (5.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess; os_name != "nt" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.1->notebook) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jinja2->notebook) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune>=0.8.1 in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbformat->notebook) (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: futures in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4->notebook) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4->notebook) (3.4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: backports_abc>=0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4->notebook) (0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.2.0->notebook) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (40.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appnope; sys_platform == "darwin" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (1.0.15)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (2.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->notebook) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser>=3.5; python_version == "2.7" in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from entrypoints>=0.2.2->nbconvert->notebook) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: functools32; python_version == "2.7" in /Users/chengtie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat->notebook) (3.2.3.post2)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: scandir; python_version < "3.5" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3"->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (1.9.0)
You are using pip version 19.0.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Ties-MBP:10studio-4 chengtie$ jupyter notebook
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Ties-MBP:10studio-4 chengtie$ jupyter-notebook
-bash: jupyter-notebook: command not found
```

Comment: As you can see from the messages, your computer has Python and pip but that is woefully outdated because Apple only really  meant it to be used for the system. You'll need Python 3 and you'll have an easier time of it using conda or a venv (or both) to isolate and manage this. See [here](https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/) , [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-python-environments-using-conda-32e9f2779307), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58068850/8508004).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally installed first `conda`, then did `conda install -c conda-forge notebook`.