# How to install Jupyter notebook and launch notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, installation

I am stuck trying to load Jupyter.  I have a feeling it might be a update issue, but i am not sure how to fix it.

I got a little traction when I typed in `pip install notebook`, and then it gave me this error after downloading several files.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win3
2" (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core>=
4.6.1->notebook)
```

When I try to type in jupyter notebook it gives me this message.

> 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Please take a look at this to understand the components of a good question [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, what is "mosh training video"? And could you elaborate on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, what you want to install. Sorry, I am not cleared? Jupyter notebook or want to update it?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it is a training video on YouTube.  I am attempting to get python to load Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error messages you've shared, I'm assuming you're performing this on a Windows OS.

After installing jupyter on Windows it's not directly added to your PATH and cannot directly be executed from the Command Line.

I see two options here:

My suggestion would be to install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual). In the Anaconda prompt, you should be able to start a notebook straight away.

If you really want to, you could opt to change your system settings so that you can run jupyter from the Command Line. Suggestions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/running-jupyter-via-command-line-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

To install jupyter notebook you can use this command:

```
pip install jupyter
```

To run your notebook. Just type

```
jupyter notebook
```

and if you are getting this error again than  the second option is download Anaconda.