# 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I type jupyter notebook in cmd I get the following error :

'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

whereas when I type jupyter-notebook it successfully opens the notebook.

Why am I facing this error?
(I have jupyter installed and I was able to open the notebook for the very first time after installation with jupyter notebook command but not from second times ownwards)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running jupyter via command line on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/running-jupyter-via-command-line-on-windows)

Answer (score 3):

Please try this command; first

```
$ py -m notebook
```

Otherwise

```
$ python -m pip install jupyter --user
$ jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `command prompt`, You can use `Anaconda prompt (Anaconda)` to open your `jupyter notebook`

[image]

`jupyter notebook` command will work in `anaconda prompt`

Answer (score 1):

1.Open cmd.

2.Type: pip install jupyter notebook, Use `pip install jupyter`.

3.Now Type: `python -m notebook`.

Answer (score 0):

For first time use of jupyter notebook, just open the anaconda prompt and type:

```
> pip install jupyter
```

then open the notebook directly

```
> jupyter notebook
```

that's it.