# 'Jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, miniconda

I have miniconda properly installed in my Windows 10 Laptop and path added as well, I have been using it for Django for 1year plus and recently I decided to go into Data Science and needed to use Jupyter Notebook, after using this command

`conda install -c conda-forge notebook`

to install Jupyter Notebook and running
`jupyter notebook`

on my terminal I had this error:

`'Jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

but when I install jupyter notebook using

`pip install jupyter`

everything worked fine.
My question is why did that happen? Does this mean that If I have miniconda on my laptop
I must use the pip command and only use conda when I have Anaconda installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running jupyter via command line on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/running-jupyter-via-command-line-on-windows)

Comment: No it did not I have tried it before