# Error when opening juypter notebook with command

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I can install jupyter notebook in python using `pip install jupyter notebook`. But while I am going to open jupyter notebook in system's command, I am getting following error.

```
C:\Users\BHAVIN PADHIYAR>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried to install and open openpyxl also in same manner but every time I am facing same error.

Kindly advise me solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" when running Jupyter on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/how-to-fix-jupyter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-oper)