# Running jupyter notebook from cmd

Tags: python, cmd, jupyter

I've downloaded Anaconda, and tried to run jupyter notebook from the command prompt on windows. For some reason, whenever I do it I get the following error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Albert

Comment: Could you add more details? Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: the executable is not in your system path, try running full path or adding the directory of jupyter in your system env variables

Comment: @BradleyRobinson that's a windows error

Comment: please see the discussion to your issue on here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134225/jupyter-from-cmd-line-in-windows

Comment: as @GonzalesGokhan suggested in the comment-section you may have to look over it first.
or try this among the list of programs click on anaconda-prompt and type the command 'jupyter notebook' if path is properly set then it should work

Answer (score 0):

On windows, the installer can offer you to **add the variable to the path**, so that you can use it in command line (it is marked as "not recommended").

I suggest that you uninstall and reinstall Anaconda and that you choose this option.

Restart your command prompt and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -3):

```
(base) C:\Users\HOME>E:

(base) E:\>cd E:\jupyter\test
```

after entering these commands wait for some time and it redirects to jupyter notebook

Comment: Please explain how this will help the user.

Comment: How do you know that they have installed it to the E drive? How do you know that they even *have* an E drive?