# Error running jupyter --version: How to install ijavascript for Jupyter on Windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

It says https://www.npmjs.com/package/ijavascript

> In Windows, Anaconda offers a convenient distribution to install Python and many other packages, such as Jupyter and IJavascript.

But it isn't explained how. Neither on Anaconda site (once Anaconda is already installed).

Update: I know about

```
npm install -g ijavascript
ijsinstall
```

But then what's difference with Linux ? Because I got this error, I thought there was something specific on Windows.

> Error running `jupyter --version`
>   Error: Command failed: jupyter --version
>   'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should probably say "such as Jupyter, where IJavascript can run", but [just like the documentation says](http://n-riesco.github.io/ijavascript/doc/install.md.html#windows)

1. Anaconda installs Jupyter for you
2. You need Nodejs and NPM for ijavascript to work

Then

```
npm install -g ijavascript
```

Followed by

```
ijsinstall
```

You need to run `jupyter` from the Anaconda prompt, or add Anaconda's executable binaries to your `PATH` (which is an option during installation). As that error is directly from CMD, it has really nothing to do with Anaconda, Jupyter, or ijavascript directly, but rather you are missing some OS setup

Comment: See update: I forgot to mention I already tried that, it didn't work, I got an error: Error running jupyter --version Error: Command failed: jupyter --version 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You should either learn about what the `PATH` variable on your OS means and how to change it, or search that error and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134225/jupyter-from-cmd-line-in-windows

Comment: I never said to run the jupyter command anyway, so I'm confused why you're doing so... Your question made me think that you already were able to run Jupyter and you just wanted Javascript support in it

Comment: I added C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 to path and I still get the same error.

Comment: Look in that folder. Do you see a file named jupyter?

Comment: There's a lot of files and folders but I can't see jupyter, I can see python.exe and Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe

Comment: 1) The Anaconda installer already asks if you want it added to the PATH, and you should check the box. 2) The **Anaconda Prompt** is where you can enter the jupyter command, if you see the question I linked above, otherwise, I trust your ability to search elsewhere for how to add jupyter to your Windows CMD PATH, as this question was originally for ijavascript

Answer (score 0):

Run ‘pip3 install jupyter‘ in the command shell.

Look through this site to get some help. Google and YouTube will be very good friends to get this set up.

[tutorial](https://leifengtechblog.wordpress.com/2015/10/27/install-and-run-jupyter-ipython-notebook-on-windows/)

Comment: Jupyter does not come with ijavascript